# Hector SLAM+SICK (use_tf_scan_transformation true or false?)

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, hector, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am getting some troubles with Hector SLAM

with (use_tf_scan_transformation=true) I get this map:
[image: image description]

with (use_tf_scan_transformation=false) I get this map:
[image: image description]

Of course the second one is much better (in the first, it seems that hector can't do mapping longer them X feets). Anyone can help-me and explain-me why this happens?

If anyone wants to try build a map with the bag file, please download:
bag file: http://fbnsantos.com/Download/bag.tar.gz (in this bag please ignore the map in map topic, and use the launch and consider mapHector)
launch file: http://fbnsantos.com/Download/ProAGV_Mapping_Hector_Slam_1.launch

We have two laser scanners, but we are interested only in Nav350Scan (which is a Sick Laser). We have developed the driver for this laser, so if you suspect that the problem is in publish data please tell-me. If anyone known other driver for this laser (Sick Nav 350 Scan) please tell advise-me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48778/hector-slam+sick-(use_tf_scan_transformation-true-or-false?)/) by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 346 on 2012-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That parameter is undocumented for a reason ;) and basically only meant for debugging. If set to false, the LIDAR scan is not transformed using tf and just used as is for mapping (should work if it is parallel to the ground plane all the time and fail quickly if it experiences roll/pitch motion). It's unusual that mapping just stops when se_tf_scan_transformation is set to true however. Is there any output on the terminal?

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on 2012-11-26**:
Thanks for your  answer (it helped to clarify the problem). I don't get any error output. I will explore laser node to see if there is any problem.